# Cómo hacer un organigrama en VISIO, utilizando programación C# y SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-office

Hola estoy trabajando en la parte de como hacer un organigrama en VISIO pero con programación C#, ademas tomar los datos de una base de datos SQL Server.

Hasta Ahorita solo llevo crear documentos, y rectángulos.
Gracias.

Este código abre un documento de Visio (Office)

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strFileName = "C:\\carpeta\\carpeta\\carpeta\\testOrg.vsdx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application vsApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document docVisio = vsApp.Documents.Add(strFileName);
Page pgVisio = docVisio.Pages[1];
Shapes shpVisio = pgVisio.Shapes;
int intCnt = shpVisio.Count;
string[] strShapeText = new string[intCnt];

printProperties(pgVisio.Shapes);
txtProperties.Text = strProperties;
}
```

El siguiente código crea un Shape (Rectángulo) (shape.Text, es un Label)

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application visapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document doc = visapp.Documents.Add("");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Page page = visapp.ActivePage;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape shape = page.DrawRectangle(1, 1, 5, 4);
//shape = visapp.ActivePage.DropConnected()
//page.ConnectionsAdded
shape.Text = "Hello World";
}
```

El siguiente Link tiene algo a lo que busco, pero aun no lo puedo generar.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109558/Creating-VISIO-Organigrams-using-C

Comparto también el código de mi conexión a Base de Datos

```
class Conexion
    {
        static string conectionString = "Server=MISERVER;Database=MIDATABASE;Uid=USER;Pwd=PASS;";
        protected SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conectionString);

        /// <summary>
        /// Busca los datos dependiendo del parent id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parentId">Es la relacion el ID</param>
        /// <returns>DataTable con la informacion</returns>
        public DataTable getParentIDs(int parentId)
        {
            SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            try
            {
                this.sqlcon.Open();
                cmmd.Connection = this.sqlcon;
                cmmd.CommandText = "select * from tabla_a (nolock) where parentid = @parentid";
                cmmd.Parameters.Add("@parentid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = parentId;
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmmd;
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                this.sqlcon.Close(); 
                return dt;
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Aviso: " + ex.Message);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lo que pides no es algo que se ajuste al formato del sitio. Te aconsejo que borres la pregunta antes de recibir votos negativos. Regresa con preguntas más específicas.

Comment: Pero es algo que se puede hacer y no se como hacerlo, de eso se trata el sitio, me podras explicar, ya que no entiendo entonces de que se trata el sitio

Comment: @Jiorchovic Quiere decir que pongas un ejemplo de lo que has intentado y en qué te atascas. Nadie te va a responder con el programa entero ya hecho, aquí se resuelven dudas concretas.

Comment: @AsieR_2, no espero que me resuelvan el programa entero, esperaba unos links o algo de ayuda, no trabas en mi pregunta, creo que no se ve muy bien que soy nuevo, con estos comentarios ni dan ganas de seguir en esta pagina. Gracias!

Comment: No tomes a mal mi comentario. Es una recomendación de como usar el sitio (por lo mismo no di un voto negativo pero otros podrían hacerlo). Buscando en internet hay varios ejemplos de como hacerlo, pero en las sugerencias de uso de este sitio se pide no responder sólo con links y el tema puede ser muy amplio para tratarlo como una simple respuesta. Eso se explica en el recorrido. https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que leas [ask], [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: podrias completar la pregunta agregando ese codigo que usaste para crear documentos y rectangulos. Cuando dices Visio te refieres al soft de office? Ademas veo que mencionas tomar los datos de una db, esto sabes como realizarlo? has intentado algo usando ado.net o entity framework

Comment: @orlandoDeLaRosa, gracias lo hare, para mejorar.,

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, Muy bien ahorita en un momento agrego el codigo de ejemplo, y agregando informacion de Visio (Office) y conexiones de ADO.NET. GRACIAS

Comment: ¿Sabes y tienes la parte de base de datos? ¿Qué es lo que no consigues? Por eso te dije que faltan cosas @Jiorchovic, no es a malas, es difícil ayudar así.

Comment: @AsieR_2, Estoy en eso, en un rato mas subo esa parte. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué tal va la cosa?

Comment: @AsieR_2, Hola buen día, encontre un ejemplo  y en un rato mas, subo el codigo de SQL Server que tengo para las conexiones.                                       https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/how-to-automate-visio-with-visual-basic-.net

Comment: Vale, tienes el `DataTable` que te devuelve la BD. ¿Qué es lo que te falta ahora? ¿Sabrías generar lo que quieres con información inventada que no sea de BD?

Comment: @AsieR_2, Lo que me falta es hacer la relación de Shape (Rectángulos), pero me falta conocimiento que es en lo que ando, una vez que tenga eso ya podre seguir con la BD, espero haber explicado lo que me falta.

Comment: @Jiorchovic ¿Te refieres a las líneas que unen los rectángulos entre sí?

Comment: @AsieR_2, así es las lineas que se hacen, ahorita estoy trabajando en un ejemplo que aun no lo puedo ejecutar correctamente, mas tarde compartiré para que lo puedan ver.

Comment: @Jiorchovic Ok, ahora deberías intentar conseguir hacer esas líneas como en el ejemplo. ¿No te funciona el ejemplo que has adjuntado? Por lo que veo se puede descargar.

Comment: @AsieR_2, asi es, solo dame oportunidad para poder subirlo a git o algún repositorio, para compartirlo y comentarles el error con el que estoy trabajando. Gracias

Comment: @JoseCansecoJiorchovic Cómo quedó esto? Fuiste capaz de conseguirlo?

Comment: Hola @AsieR_2, si al fin pude echarlo andar, solo en un par de días subo como solucionarlo ya que no puedo subir todo pero si la idea de la solución, lo malo fue que al final ya no lo quisieron con Visio. :/